# Cursor misbehaving in UWP TextBox

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Let's say I have a ViewModel with a data type of `float` and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
private float Amount;
```

And then in my UI:

```xaml
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Amount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

What happens is that when I'm trying to type the character `.` (period), the text cursor goes back to the start and just appears right after two presses of period. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: i posted this on mobile so forgive me for any format issues.

Comment: i think one possible solution could be a value converter or maybe somewhere in the setter of this property, to not notify when a period is pressed or maybe something like that.

Comment: Is the field really just a `private` field or do you have an actual property that fires the `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: @MartinZikmund yes i do have a propertyChanged event. just didn't put in the code but i've updated the description of this question

Comment: It would be useful if you put in the whole code of the `Amount` property, including the getter and setter, as I suspect the cause will be there

Comment: @MartinZikmund will do once  i can get my hands on a laptop. but basically it's just the normal getter/setter that calls propertyChanged event.

Comment: And the cursor jumps right after typing the dot? It surprises me, because the binding itself happens only after the `TextBox` loses focus, not immediately (it would have to be classic `Binding` with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to have this behavior of updating after each keystroke)

Comment: @MartinZikmund yes. i do have that in my code. so i was wondering if it was caused by that and so i did try to remove it. i re-run and still the same. i will post my code when i can and.try to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the code when `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` as mentioned in the comments. The problem is that `PropertyChanged` causes the binding to update immediately after each keystroke. Because of this the behavior is quite upredicatable when the input does not contain a valid `float`. I have seen three different behaviors so far. Once only one digit is entered and period right after that, the binding sometimes converts it to a decimal:

[image: Conversion]

But sometimes this did not happen and the control just let me enter `3.` without any change. The behavior is seems really random. The key is that the `value` that is set to the backing property is then reflected in the UI by virtue of `PropertyChanged` event and data binding, which causes the text to change and cursor to jump.

Simply said, the problem here is the fact that the property is a `float` while the input accepts any `string`. The solution to your problem could be to use a `string` property for the binding, like `AmountText` and then in the setter verify that the text is actually a valid `float`, parse it and manually set the `Amount` property. This way you would preserve the "immediate" updating of the value as soon as a valid input is entered while you would also avoid the weird behavior you are seeing.

Also check out the [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) and its [`NumericUpDown` control](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/NumericUpDown), which might be a better solution for your goal as it provides a natural way for the user to enter numeric values.

Comment: Just like i thought it is. i need to validate the value being set in my setter to accept that kind of input. thanks. i'll accept this as an answer once i can verify on my end. thanks again

Comment: Glad to help :-) .

Comment: yes this is exactly what i thought it was. but i ended up forcing the textbox element to lose focus so it will update bindings since i can't seem to get it right in the setter and might require more time which i don't have right now. i'll get back to it in the future for now, i'll just provide a temporary solution which is to lose focus on the textbox.